# Multiple query with many tables in MySql

Tags: mysql

I have 4 tables, and how I can create on query for result.

**table** card

```
id name
1 card1
2 card2
3 card3
4 card4
```

**table** visit

```
id card_id
1     1
2     1
3     1
4     1
5     2
6     2
7     3
8     4
```

**table** like

```
id card_id
1     1
2     2
3     2
4     2
5     3
6     3
7     3
8     4
```

**table** favorite

```
id card_id
1     1
2     1
3     1
4     1
5     3
6     3
7     3
8     4
```

**result**

```
 name visit  like favorite
 card1   4      1      4
 card2   2      3      0
 card3   1      3      3
 card4   1      1      1
```

Comment: and what you have tried so for ? just posting details with no effort is not a question

Comment: if have any relation with tables..

Comment: i need to get in one query for get name and counts of other tables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT C.Name,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM VISIT AS V WHERE V.Card_Id = C.Id) AS Visits,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `LIKE` AS L WHERE L.Card_Id = C.Id) AS Likes,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM FAVORITE AS F WHERE F.Card_Id = C.Id) AS Favorite
FROM Card AS C
```

Comment: syntax error, you should remove the `,` line `(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM FAVORITE AS F WHERE F.Card_Id = C.Id) AS Favorite, `

Comment: thanks, copy paste hell

Answer (score 1):

I would use this query:

```
SELECT
  card.name,
  SUM(visit) AS visit,
  SUM(`like`) AS `like`,
  SUM(favorite) AS favorite
FROM
  card INNER JOIN
  (
    SELECT card_id, COUNT(*) as visit, 0 as `like`, 0 as favorite
    FROM visit
    GROUP BY card_id
    UNION ALL
    SELECT card_id, 0 as visit, COUNT(*) as `like`, 0 as favorite
    FROM `like`
    GROUP BY card_id
    UNION ALL
    SELECT card_id, 0 as visit, 0 as `like`, COUNT(*) as favorite
    FROM favorite
    GROUP BY card_id
  ) counts ON card.id = counts.card_id
GROUP BY card.id, card.name
```

Comment: not simple syntax) I think card.name in the end not needed

Comment: and why this variant differs from the above writing?

Comment: @dev.nikolaz card.name is not needed in this case, mysql allows you to skip it and in this particular context it is correct, but I prefer to use more standard sql. I'm not a big fan of using subqueries in SELECT clause, but sometimes they are perfecly fine and they are certalny easier to understand